# Middleman variables visibility in config.rb and pages

Tags: ruby, middleman

I'm missing something about visibility of variables.
In my config.rb i'm using a data structure to generate dynamic pages:

```
    @pages = [
    {
      id: "cookies",
      title: "Happy Chocolate Chip Cookies", 
      quote: "These cute cookies are full of sweet chocolate and ready to give you energy!",
      content: "Orecchini a monachella. Realizzati in fimo, dipinti a mano e rivestiti con vernice lucida."
    },
    ....]



 @pages.each do |p|
    page "/creations/#{p[:id]}.html", :proxy => "item-template.html", :ignore => true do 
      @tile = p
    end
  end
```

The pages generation goes well, no problem with that. But..

How can i access this data structure also in order to provide dynamic links to the generated pages? I would like to be able to create an index page (let's call it creations.html) with the following code:

```
    <ul>
    <% @pages.each do |tile| %>
        <li><a href="creations/<%= tile[:id]%>.html">
            <%= tile[:title] %>
        </a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create a custom helper, you can use a yaml data file to populate your template and generate the list of links. Let me explain.

On the same level as source and build directories make sure you create a data directory.
ie:

- build
- source
- data

Inside this create a file called "pages.yml" (for example).

This file needs to be specifically formatted so be careful (or use a [yaml parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) to make sure you don't have any errors - like a missing comma or escaped quote).

Using the data  in your config.rb file, an example would be something like:

```
- id: "cookies"
  title: "Happy Chocolate Chip Cookies"
  quote: "These cute cookies are full of sweet chocolate and ready to give you energy!"
  content: "Orecchini a monachella. Realizzati in fimo, dipinti a mano e rivestiti con vernice lucida."

 - id: "bacon"
   title: "Smoked bacon bits"
   quote: "everything tastes better with bacon!"
   content: "blah"
```

etc...

Now, in your config.rb file replace **@pages.each do |p|** with **data.pages.each do |p|**

data.pages.each loops through each item in the newly created yaml file

You can then simply reference the same file in your index file (creations.html) like so:

```
<ul>
  <% data.pages.each do |tile| %>
    <li><a href="creations/<%= tile[:id]%>.html">
       <%= tile[:title] %>
    </a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I had a similar problem around dynamic pages which you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823169/pass-dynamic-content-to-template-in-middleman/14873904#14873904)

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps add a helper that returns the `@pages` data structure in your file `creations.erb`. I.e. in your `config.rb` file add:

```
helpers do
  def dynamic_pages()
    @pages
  end
end
```

and then in your `creations.erb` have:

```
<ul>
  <% dynamic_pages.each do |tile| %>
    <li><a href="creations/<%= tile[:id]%>.html">
       <%= tile[:title] %>
    </a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And, if you want to reference dynamic pages in your dynamic pages(!), a helper could generate that html and you could call the ... nah, never mind!