# Pass dynamic content to template in Middleman

Tags: yaml, middleman

I'm building a static site using Middleman that has a portfolio section of all the client's recent projects.
The portfolio section will display project thumbnail images in a 3 X 3 gallery fashion and, when clicked on, will open their co-responding html page inside a lightbox.

The layout for the pages inside the light box is the same so rather than markup each individual page, I thought there would be a way for Middleman handling the content served from a yaml data file (projects.yml) using [a link.

Here's what I've got in my config.rb file

```
###
# Page options, layouts, aliases and proxies
###

# A path which all have the same layout
with_layout :popup do
  page "/projects/*"
end

# Proxy (fake) files
# page "/this-page-has-no-template.html", :proxy => "/template-file.html" do
#   @which_fake_page = "Rendering a fake page with a variable"
# end
data.projects.details.each do |pd|
  proxy "/projects/#{pd[:client_name]}.html", "/projects/template.html", locals: { project: pd }, ignore: true
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok so after some digging I came across the two posts below which helped me under stand how dynamic pages work in middleman. (Unfortunately there's not a lot of doco and the Middleman example for Dynamic pages is really basic)

http://benfrain.com/understanding-middleman-the-static-site-generator-for-faster-prototyping/
http://forum.middlemanapp.com/discussion/134/best-way-to-use-yaml-same-html-but-parameter-driven-data-fixed/p1

My solution...

data/projects.yml (contains project details)

```
details:
  - client: "Company X"
    title: "Company X Event"
    video_url: ""
    logo: 
      - "logo_companyx.gif"
    image_path: "/img/projects/companyx"
    total_images: 10
    content: "<p>Blah blah blah</p>"
    responsibilities: 
      "<li>Something</li>
      <li>Some task</li>"
```

config.rb:

```
data.projects.details.each do |pd|
    proxy "/projects/#{pd[:client]}.html", "/projects/template.html", :layout => false, :locals => { :project => pd }, :ignore => true
end
```

The trick with the snippet above is passing the entire project data object to the template via a proxy using locals and setting the layout to false so it doesn't inherit the default site layout (as I - or the client rather - want to display these in a lightbox popup)

The last step in the process was to create /projects/template.html.erb (in the source folder), declaring the following at the top of the template

```
<% p = locals[:project] %>
```

This allowed me to output each property of the p object within template.html.erb.

eg:

```
<%= p[:title] %>
```

I hope this helps someone as it took me a few days of playing around and LOTS of searching online for example or hints.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out Middleman. If you have a project that you'd be willing to open source, I'd like to see. Struggling with the docs.

Comment: this blog as hosted its project source on github: https://github.com/DarrenN/darrenknewton.com

Comment: Hey your url is busted to the blog. Would love to read it though. I love the solution but I am a little hesitant about proxy and layout: false.It may just be in my head, but I haven't seen that and feels like it's fighting middleman. Could absolutely be wrong here though.

Comment: Hey @BlaineHatab, sorry I ported my blog from heroku to github since writing the comment above. New url is http://tomgillard.com/blog/2013-12-31-page-alive/. 

As to your concerns regarding proxy and layout => false. These are set in config.rb. I have a link to the proxies section from the middleman docs in my blog post above.

All layout => false is doing is telling middleman that you don't want to generate a page layout for the template.html file.

Hope this helps :-)